# PropertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null).GetType() returns "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, propertyinfo

I'm trying to convert a MembershipUserCollection to a DataSet to be used in a GridView and I have this helper class that will loop through all the membership rows and properties and get the values and types and shove them into DataRows.

It works while there is a value for the property, but when there is a null value, it breaks returning the message, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

In this particular example, it breaks on the Comment field if when it's value is "null".

Here's my code where it occurs:

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo in PropertyInfos)
    {
        Type oType = oPropertyInfo.GetValue(oData, null).GetType(); <-- error
        oDataRow[oPropertyInfo.Name.ToString()] = Convert.ChangeType(oPropertyInfo.GetValue(oData, null), oType);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the type to what it already is?

Comment: This is code that I got on the net, now that I look at it I don't know why the ChangeType method is there.  I'm really just trying to get the type of the property and add it to the datarow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetType()` is an instance method.  The property value returns either an `object` or `null`.  Any instance method call on a null reference will cause the error you are receiving.  The `GetType()` method is throwing the exception when you try to call it on a null property (in your case, the Comment property).

You should instead use `oPropertyInfo.PropertyType` to get the property type, (which is faster anyway).

Comment: OP is trying to get the `Type` of `oData` not `oPropertyInfo`

Comment: @hunter: `PropertyType` will return the type the property is defined to hold. This is the right value for creating a `DataTable`, which it appears the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @hunter, `Type oType = oPropertyInfo.GetValue(oData, null).GetType()` sure looks like an attempt to get the property type to me

Comment: @smartcaveman, I tried using the `oPropertyInfo.PropertyType`, but that also throws an error when the value is null.  There must be a way to deal with null values.

Comment: @Kahanu, Your error must be caused by the `Convert.ChangeType(oPropertyInfo.GetValue(oData, null), oType)`.  `propertyInfo.PropertyType` is not tied to an instance

Comment: @smartcaveman - I thought of that, but it fails on the preceding line, not on the line with the `Convert.ChangeType()` method, even when I use `oPropertyInfo.PropertyType` on the first line of the loop.

Comment: @Kahanu, impossible.  Maybe you need to rebuild your project, but a non-null `PropertyInfo` instance's `PropertyType` property will NEVER throw that exception, and `nonNullType.GetProperties()` will not return null PropertyInfo objects.